# Git path pattern - search files ignoring folders and extension

Tags: git

I have many folders inside repo. I need some command to select only required files to procedure. Folder names should be ignored. Would be nice to have 2 ways - ignoring case and not ignoring.

Like
`git add *quest* (with some adjustments)`
to add

```
src/windows/QuestWindow.src
res/out/QuestWindow.compiled
logs/123QUEST.log
doc/quests.xls
```

but not

```
buggedQuestsFolder/broken1.src
buggedQuestsFolder/broken2.src
```

I hope somebody understood idea.

Answer (score 0):

Make a `.gitignore` in project's home with the paths you don't want to follow

```
buggedQuestsFolder/broken1.src
buggedQuestsFolder/broken2.src
```

[This](https://github.com/github/gitignore) is a nice git collection of useful gitinores

for case-insensitiveness in ignored pattern you have to add the multiple choices

```
[Qq]uest[Tt]o[Bb]e[Ii]gnored
```

or write it explicitely

Comment: No, I need all those files in git. Question is to "git add" only "quest" files, then commit them. All other files will be commited in next commit.